# How to include a controller with a Ruby on Rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm trying to contribute to an open source project and I need a controller to handle a couple of forms that need to be submitted in.

I created these controllers inside a directory inside the gem called `app/controllers/gemname/my_controller.rb`.

However, when I try to access the controller, it seems not to be loaded (I get a name error just as if I typed something like NonExistentController).

How do I load my controller with the gem?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your `MyController` defined inside `Gemname` module? If it's not rails will expect it to be placed in `app/controllers/my_controller.rb`.

Comment: Please read this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html

Comment: KL-7, how do I define MyController inside of the Gemname module? taro, thanks for the info. I did, that doesn't contain the information I'm looking for though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's assume your gem is called `MyGem` and you have a controller called `SuperController` that you want to use in the app. Your controller should be defined as:

```
module MyGem
  class SuperController < ApplicationController
    def whatever
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

and in your gem directory it should live at `app/controllers/my_gem/super_controller.rb` (*not* under the `lib` folder). Check out the [source for Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) as they do the same thing.

[Edit] You may learn something from [A Guide To Starting Your Own Rails Engine Gem](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&ie=UTF-8&q=cache%3Acoding.smashingmagazine.com%2F2011%2F06%2F23%2Fa-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem%2F&oq=cache%3Acoding.smashingmagazine.com%2F2011%2F06%2F23%2Fa-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem%2F&aqs=chrome..69i57.1375j0j4&bav=on.2,or.&biw=1920&bih=941&dpr=1&ech=1&psi=1aP-Vf25JsmfaL6wp-AK.1442751446797.3&ei=1aP-Vf25JsmfaL6wp-AK&emsg=NCSR&noj=1) regarding your current project.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I love the `guide link` you mentioned.

Comment: I was struggling with this all yesterday. I think today will be a lot easier. Thanks!

Comment: @Brandon How much have things changed in Rails Engines between Rails 3 and 4?

Answer (score 0):

The guide in Brandon's answer is very helpful but only applies to rails 3.0. Since 3.1 you can create a plugin. Like this: `rails plugin new my_engine --mountable`

See this helpful guide:
http://namick.tumblr.com/post/17663752365/how-to-create-a-gemified-plugin-with-rails-3-2-rspec
(> Rails 3.0)

Rails official guide (edge):
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html

Old enginex:
https://github.com/josevalim/enginex
(3.0 only)