# Rails own gem and uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to made my own gem, but I am still getting an error,

Here is my gem structure:
    order
    - app
      - controllers
        - order_controller.rb
    - lib
      - order
      order.rb

And content of the order_controller.rb:

```
class Order::OrderController < ApplicationController
    def index
       puts "asd"
    end
end
```

I've got order gem added to the main application Gemfil.

I defined my root to lead to index action of that controller:

```
root :to => "order/order#index"
```

but when I try to access homepage I get:

> uninitialized constant Order::OrderController

What I've done wrong?

Comment: I tried both ways, additionally I also tried solution described in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689142/how-to-include-a-controller-with-a-ruby-on-rails-gem), but output is always the same...

Answer (score 0):

Did you run bundle install after adding the gem in the Gemfile? By the way, why are you making a gem for that structure instead of making a Rails project with that structure?